# Magento - Install EAV Attribute via Installer

Tags: magento

Hey guys im using the installer in my module to add a new EAV product attribute to the Default attribute set. So far its working great, but there are 2 little things that bother me.

```
public function getDefaultEntities(){

    return array(
        'catalog_product' => array(
            'entity_model'                      => 'catalog/product',
            'attribute_model'                   => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
            'table'                             => 'catalog/product',
            'additional_attribute_table'        => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
            'entity_attribute_collection'       => 'catalog/product_attribute_collection',
            'attributes'        => array(
                'disable_sale' => array(
                    'group'                     => 'General',
                    'label'                     => 'Disable Sale',
                    'type'                      => 'int',
                    'input'                     => 'select',
                    'source'                    => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
                    'global'                    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'is_visible_on_front'       => true,
                    'used_in_product_listing'   => true,
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

I want my attribute set to be visible on product details page and catalog listing per default.

```
'is_visible_on_front'       => true,
'used_in_product_listing'   => true,
```

The problem is that both values are not set to be visible.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with attributes per-se, but try both 'integers' 1 AND 'string' "1" in your code and see if it works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you somehow removing the attribute from the DB every time you test this?  If not, can you change something like 'label' and see it change as well?

Comment: Yes i remove the attribute and also the setup entry in the core_resource table.

Answer (score 0):

is_visible_on_front change to visible_on_front  and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here at stackoverflow:
[Magento module setup/installer script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990441/magento-module-setup-installer-script)

Setup class should extend from

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup
```

Now the installer is aware of the additional attributes and its working like a charme.

Comment: Well thats not very fair, you didn't say you weren't extending that as your DB setup. ;)